# Two css files in html with different settings

Tags: html, css

I have two style sheets and one html page. Can I use one of the style sheets inside a div in the center of a page? I'd like to do that because both styles have the different settings for h1, h2, th and so on.

Comment: You shouldn't. This is why you have classes.

Comment: And which style sheet would take precedent? As mentioned, just use classes.

Comment: Seems like you will want to class out your elements and apply css to those classes. If you have two CSS sheets the second one will overwrite the css of the first one, if they overlap.

Answer (score 1):

HTML 5 introduces [the `scoped` attribute](http://html5doctor.com/the-scoped-attribute/).

This will allow you to have a `<style>` element (not a `<link>` to an external stylesheet) that applies to only part of the document.

Browser support is weak (latest stats I have are from [Sep 2011 when there was zero support](http://html5doctor.com/the-scoped-attribute/#support)), so this almost certainly isn't practical for you.

---

The usual solution is to use a single stylesheet. Wrap the section of the document in an element with an `id` and use that id in selectors with a [descendant combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#descendant-combinators) to override all the applicable styles from the wider document.

```
h1 { 
    color: red;
}

#mySection h1 {
    color: black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Specificity will determine which one takes precedence.  If you choose to go that route, you can add classes to differentiate between one style of H1 or another.

However, you're also going to take a performance hit for loading two CSS documents via HTTP.

Personally, I'd work out my styles by class in one document.  For instance:

```
h1 {
    color:orange;
}

.style1 h1 {
    font-size: 600%;
    color: red;
}

.style2 h1 {
    font-size: 20%;
    color: yellow;
}
```

The key is to keep it simple.  Think about how maintainable your method would be over the long term if your site got really huge.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the headlines when for example in a div, if you have something like:

```
<div class="example">
    <h1>Fancy headline</h1>
</div>
```

You can use a style like .example h1 {...} to only give that headline a specific style. Thats the cascading in css ;)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to specify which section of your HTML would use which stylesheet be more specific in your stylesheet so you don't run into style collisions. Example;

HTML:

```
<div id="a">
    <div class="b">
        <h1>c</h1>
    </div>

    <h1>d</h1>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#a h1 {
    /* style */
}

#a .b h1 {
    /* another style */
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use as many stylesheets as you like.  But its better to combine all styles into one sheet, so that your page doesn't have to request multiple files from the webserver.

But more to the point: how to style the same elements differently on a page?

A couple of methods:

1) By using `class` or `id`.  If you have an tag `<h2 class='regular'>` and `<h2 class='highlight'>` you can then style them differently.

```
.regular {
color: #000000;
}
.highlight {
color: #0000ff;
}
```

2) You can also style things according to thier association with other elements.  For example if your page structure is:

```
<body>
    <div class='lvl-one'>
        <p class='lvl-two'></p>
    </div>
</body>
```

You can target the `<p class='lvl-two'>` without even the `class` like this:

```
div p {
    font-size:24px;
}
```

PS.  You should not have multiple `h1` tags on your page -- its bad for SEO.